# How to call escaping function one after another only when condition matches in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, escaping, closures

```
func conditionalCalling() {

if 1==1 {
    hitFirstAPI {
        if 2==2 {
            hitSecondAPI {
                if 3==3 {
                    hitThirdAPI {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if 3==3 {
            hitThirdAPI {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
else if 2==2 {
    hitSecondAPI {
        if 3==3 {
            hitThirdAPI {
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
else if 3==3 {
    hitThirdAPI {
        
    }
}

}


    func hitFirstAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {
        
    }
    func hitSecondAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {
        
    }
    func hitThirdAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {
        
    }
```

Above code gives a simple idea of my questions, in simple words, ***if condition matches*** I want to call functions ***one after another*** if not check for next condition and if that's true call the next function and so on...

How can I do that in minimum lines of code?

My thought initially:

```
func conditionalCaling() {
    if 1==1 {
        hitFirstAPI {
            
        }
    }
    if 2==2 {
        hitSecondAPI {
            
        }
    }
    if 3==3 {
        hitThirdAPI {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Although this approach will call function only if condition matches, it will ***call all functions together***, ***NOT*** after one function escapes closure block.

Topmost code seems to be the solution but I want to do that in minimum lines of code, is there any other better approach than if else statements all around ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your first attempt into smaller reasonable chunks like this.

```
import Foundation

func conditionalCalling() {
    initiateFlow {
        print("Done!")
    }
}
func initiateFlow(done: @escaping ()->Void) {
    if 1==1 {
        hitFirstAPI { initiateSecondAPI(done: done) }
    } else {
        initiateSecondAPI(done: done)
    }
}
func initiateSecondAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {
    if 2==2 {
        hitSecondAPI { initiateThirdAPI(done: done) }
    } else {
        initiateThirdAPI(done: done)
    }
}
func initiateThirdAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {
    if 3==3 {
        hitThirdAPI(done: done)
    } else {
        done()
    }
}
func hitFirstAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {}
func hitSecondAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {}
func hitThirdAPI(done: @escaping ()->Void) {}
```

In above method, your checks are not unnecessarily repeated and it still does what you wanted in your first attempt (original flow).